# Display WPF modal window/dialog/panel the same way as a NSWindow can be displayed like a sheet in Cocoa

Tags: .net, wpf, cocoa, modal-dialog

I am looking for a way to display a modal window in WPF the same way as a window in Cocoa can be displayed as a sheet, i.e. it slides down from the titlebar in front of the main parent window.

My guess is that this would be accomplished by having the modal window as a user control which is loaded into a panel when displayed, and that this panel is the one which would be animated somehow from the titlebar.

Any ideas on how to do this?

*P.S: [Here](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000014.php) is a brief description of the NSWindow/sheet in case you don't what it is*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't. It's not the expected user experience on Windows. Use modal dialogs or in-window navigation instead.

Comment: It may not be the "expected" user experience on Windows, but WPF is all about customizing the user experience. Consider your specific app... if it makes sense to use a sheet-like interface element, then DO use it. It could be just the thing that sets your app apart from other "standard" (boring) Windows apps.

Comment: I beg to differ. "All about customizing the user interface" doesn't mean "throwing new paradigms in the user's face just to be frilly". It is my experience that users have trouble understanding attached windows on Windows -- just ask Apple, who had to remove them from Safari/Win32 posthaste. They look alien to the platform and have several limitations (no fine control over dwm shadows, choppy dragging etc) due to lack of underlying support. In-window popovers may be OK; full-blown sheets probably won't, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

http://doteverything.blogspot.com/2008/06/modal-dialogs-in-wpf.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys.

My main objective for this was to have a shared window for the two windows, but I do not want to make it break any expected UX either so I'll take your answers into consideration and try to make up another idea for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Sliding and Flying Windows](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFFlyingWindows.aspx) sample on CodeProject and also the Microsoft Health [Common User Interface demonstrator](http://www.mscui.net/PatientJourneyDemonstrator/) which was the (Silverlight) inspiration. The latter gives you a good idea of what's going to be pushed as both *cool* and *blessed* in corporate UI design :-)